# how to handle data-icon in jquery mobile & jquery-ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile & for some auto complete functionality I am using jquery-ui, but the problem is that the icon(>) which is on my button & the icon(>) on my list item is not showing properly, instead its showing some weird icons. Any suggestions how to fix this?
[image]

```
<input type="submit" value="More" id="more" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="b"/>
```

Comment: i have added the button's code

Comment: icon > is arrow-r not arrow-d by the way.

Comment: This works for me ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BwPLr/)). Maybe you're overriding jQuery mobile's icon styles with your own CSS rules. Check if `.ui-icon` still exposes the right background image, and if `.ui-icon-d` exposes the right values in its `background-position` rule (it should be `-216px 50%`).

Comment: i just added this to tell you guys, i know this thing!

Comment: do you have a link to the page in question that we can look at?   and can you include more of your code?  the javascript and css includes and perhaps the basic page structure.   a jsfiddle illustrating this would be ideal.

Comment: actually: here is a fork of  @FrédéricHamidi 's fiddle:   including jquery ui does infact mess up the jquery mobile icons. and the button styles!   : http://jsfiddle.net/29n8M/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read a lot about the ui auto complete not working to great in the mobile environment, I'm not sure entirely what's going on with your button though, that looks weird.

Does it look ok if you leave out the jquery ui styles?

You could just do away with jquery ui's auto complete  and try this pluginI've been using it with some good success:
http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/

**edit**:  try switching the order that you are including your styles:
put the jquery ui styles BEFORE the jquery mobile styles.

**EDIT:** 
Ok, i just tested this locally and it worked:   Put the jquery UI JAVASCRIPT  before the jquery mobile javascript and it will be ok:

here's a full test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css"/>


      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css"/>



  <style type='text/css'>
    body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}


  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){


});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <div>
<input type="button" value="More" id="more" data-icon="arrow-d" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="b"/>
    </div>
</form>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: yes when i do not add the jquery-ui script, then it works fine

Comment: That's probably a conflict between jQuery UI and jQuery Mobile's icon style rules, then...

Comment: what versions of jquery, jquery ui and jquery mobile are you using?